# Heroku redirect WWW to non WWW

Tags: heroku

I have an application on Heroku. This does not work with adding `www` at the beginning. Is there a way to make it work with `www` without using a custom domain? I want it to be on the herokuppapp subdomain but it should work with `www`.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you use the free .herokuapp.com domain then that is ONLY accessible via appname.herokuapp.com - if you want to use www. then you have to be using a custom domain.